Error: remoteMessaging' is incompatible with attribute foregroundServiceType
We have upgraded the com.salesforce.service:servicesdk to latest version 224.2.7 after that we are getting this error:

AAPT: error: 'remoteMessaging' is incompatible with attribute foregroundServiceType

We have below-mentioned configuration on our project:
targetSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 21

How do I get it to make latest version work for API 33.
